# TeamCity & Subversion: Checkout copies ALL tags to buildagent's checkout directory

Tags: svn, version-control, teamcity

We have the following URL:
URL: https://dev-01:8555/svn/Shop

We have the following structure in SubVersion

```
Shop
--trunk
--branches
--tags
```

The problem is, when I do a build, under the buildagent directory, I get every single tag in the repository copied over to the buildagent.

Is there a way to only retrieve the HEAD revision to effect the build on.

Answer (score 6):

Change: Administration -> {Project Name} -> {Build Configuration Name} Configuration -> Configuration Steps -> Version Control Settings -> edit checkout rules

Add these lines:

-:tags
-:branches

[Checkout Rules Documentations](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/VCS+Checkout+Rules)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want the trunk then the VCS path in TeamCity should be:

https://dev-01:8555/svn/Shop/trunk

As an aside - one would generally expect the path in TeamCity to be the same as the path you use to checkout your working copy unless you're working on a branch.

Comment: Thanks Murph. I actually need the level above as our build has two VCS roots. I removed the tags and branches by adding -:tags & -:branches in the checkout rules. Now I don;t end up with everything under Shop being copied to the buildagent.